# How to Change the Font Used in htmlwidgets for R?

Tags: r

I have a table that I am building using reactable in R, and want to add a title with the same font I am using in the table itself. I figured out how to add a title, but how do I change the font?

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(reactable)

reactable(head(iris, 10),
          style = list(fontFamily = 'Menlo',
                       fontSize = '14px'),
          highlight = TRUE) %>%
  htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$h1("This is my Title"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the style when you add the tag.  Right clicking on the column titles show that they are using `font-family: Menlo` (the result of you asking for `fontFamily = 'Menlo'`), so this gives you the same font:

```
reactable(head(iris, 10),
       style = list(fontFamily = 'Menlo',
                    fontSize = '14px'),
       highlight = TRUE) %>%
htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$h1("This is my Title", 
                                               style = "font-family: Menlo"))
```

You would use `style = "font-family: Menlo; font-size: 14px"` to match the size as well.